# How do I capture the key in a collection select form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
<%= f.input :divisor, collection: [["Weekly", 52], ["Monthly", 12], 
    ["Quarterly", 4]], as: :radio_buttons, label: false, input_html:
  {id: "divisor"} %>
```

The form saves the value to the db, but I also want to use the key string the user selected on the show page. I tried using a case statement in the model, like so:

```
before_save :set_plan
attr_accessor :plan

 def set_plan
case :divisor
when 52
  puts "weekly"
when 12
  puts "monthly"
when 4
  puts "quarterly"
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `case :divisor` use `case self.divisor` in your model.
If you save that collection into some table then with `self.divisor` would give the strings you'd like to.

**E.g.**
you create table `plans` like this

`id|plan_val|title 
  1| 52  | Weekly 
  2| 12  | Monthly
  3| 4   | Quarterly`

then you can write your callback like this

```
before_save :set_plan

def set_plan
  puts Plan.find_by(plan_val: self.divisor).title
end
```